# Best ActionBar compatibility libraries

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm writing an Android App and I'm trying to choose which compatibility library to choose to implement the ActionBar functionality.

I'm trying to choose between two libraries:

GreenDroid : https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

Android-Actionbar: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

From what I could gather, AA(Android-Actionbar) seems to be simpler, and easier to style. But GreenDroid has additional features which make it the more powerful solution in general(not just for an Actionbar).

I left out ActionBarSherlock because it also supports fragments, is more complicated.

IF there are others that I missed, please share!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ActionBarSherlock.

It is based on ICS code, is actively developed, and will use the native actionbar when run on ICS. It also plays nicely with the compatibility library and will let your use ICS features such as the split action bar and share providers. Probably the biggest plus is that it uses exactly the same API as ICS. If you don't need fragmetns, you certainly don't have to use them.

Green Droid offers a custom look and feel, not exactly consistent with Android UI [design guide lines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html). Android-Actiobnar is based on custom layouts and only offers basic features.

Here's a discussion (might be biased, since it's by the ABS author): http://corner.squareup.com/2012/05/actionbarsherlock-as-a-base.html

Comment: Seconding the ActionbarSherlock suggestion. It's a great library, stable, and haven't had any issues with it. I'd recommend anything Jake Wharton's worked on.

Answer (score 0):

The Android-Actionbar is better, for sure.
Couldn't think of any other ones but I am sure there are.